# Can't Connect Python Service to Mongo Server in Docker

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker file with two services running on the same network.
The purpose is to scrape data and store it in a database.

When I attempt to run the program `db_connector.py` inside service `block_scraper` I get an error (Timeout):

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: storage:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 64f24e6e941b3aa3dea67cc9, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('storage', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('storage:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>
```

As seen in the error, my most recent attempts are using the Docker service name, `storage`, to refer to the service.

I was able to get this to work fine when running both services natively outside docker. How can I get them to talk to eachother inside docker?

---

Project Tree:
|-Dockerfile
|-docker-compose.yml
|-requirements.txt
|-app/
|-|-main.py
|-|-db_connector.py

The `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.2"

services:

  storage:
    image: mongo:7.0.1-rc0
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 27017-27019:27017-27019
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    networks:
      - scraper_network

  block_scraper:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - storage
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    environment:
      - STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR=mongodb://storage:27017
    networks:
      - scraper_network

networks:
  scraper_network:
```

The Dockerfile (for `block_scraper` service):

```
# Use the official Python 3.11 image as a parent image
FROM python:3.11-slim-buster

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy in and install requirements
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -Ur requirements.txt

# Copy the application code into the container
COPY . /app

# Specify the command to run your main program
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

The `db_connector.py` file:

```
import os
import pymongo

# Create a single MongoClient instance and reuse it across calls to get_collection
mongo_host = os.environ.get("STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR")
client = pymongo.MongoClient(mongo_host)

def get_collection(mongo_db_name="blocks101", mongo_collection_name="block"):
    database = client[mongo_db_name]
    return database[mongo_collection_name]

def close():
    client.close()
```

For simplicity, lets say this is the `main.py` program:

```
from db_connector import get_collection

get_collection()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `mongodb:/<neighbour_container_name>:27017` is the only correct way to connect. Other listed variants will not work, because from inside docker container `localhost` refers to the container itself (for connection to container's host address there's `host.docker.internal`)

It seems you should set `container_name: storage` (or remove this line completely) also.

**upd:**

I have successfully reproduced your setup and connected to default database as a result:

```
root@85081a0c46fc:/app# python3
>>> import os
>>> import pymongo
>>> mongo_host = os.environ.get("STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR")
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient(mongo_host)
>>> client
MongoClient(host=['storage:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True)
```

Are you able to connect to mongo container from host?

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't resolve the issue for me. I've updated my Q to include more information.

Comment: I am able to connect too now... but never the first time. 
I think Mongo isn't ready to accept connections before `block_scraper` attempts -- which is strange in consideration to my `depends_on` clause inside `docker-compose.yml`. Is there any way to add a `healthcheck` in `docker-compose` specific for when Mongo is ready to accept external connections?

Comment: yes, you can implement healthcheck for container and use --wait flag - similar problem (and solution) was discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67805969/wait-for-specific-container-when-using-docker-compose-up-d